# The eigenvectors of hermitian are not orthogonal

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality

I am trying to solve the related questions about the matrix{{0,-i,0},{i,0,-i},{0,i,0}}. This is obviously a hermitian, but when I try to get the eigenvectors of it, what I get is v1=(-1, i*sqrt(2), 1), v2=(-1, -i*sqrt(2), 1), v3=(1, 0, 1). v1 and v2 are not orthogonal and their magnitudes are 0, how could this be possible? I think there must be something wrong but I just could not figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the inner product between complex vectors means multiplying each component of one by the complex conjugate of the corresponding component of the other and adding these products together. Therefore
$$\langle v_1,v_2\rangle=(-1)(-1)+(i\sqrt{2})(i\sqrt{2})+(1)(1)=1-2+1=0.$$
Similarly, to calculate the magnitude of a complex vector, multiply each component of the vector by its complex conjugate and sum these. With this in mind, the magnitude of $v_1$ and $v_2$ is 2.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am always confused with when and how to use complex conjugate in  complex calculations.